# cor_cophenetic behavior in randomizations

Tags: r, hclust, dendextend

I am working in R, with the `dendextend` package, trying to compare `hclusts` objects with `cop_cophenetic`.

I have two objects that rise from clustering: `clusts` and `clusts1`, and I want to compare the cophenetic correlation between them. I have a few options as below:

```
cor_cophenetic(as.phylo(clusts), as.phylo(clusts1))
[1] 0.1632751
cor_cophenetic(as.dendrogram(clusts), as.dendrogram(clusts1))
[1] 0.1632751
cor_cophenetic(clusts, clusts1)
[1] 0.689649
cor_cophenetic(as.phylo.hclust(clusts), as.phylo.hclust(clusts1))
[1] 0.1632751
```

I can also try a more direct approach with base R

```
cor(as.vector(cophenetic(clusts)), as.vector(cophenetic(clusts1)))
[1] 0.689649
```

First, I don't understand the difference between calling `cor_cophenetic` on the `hclusts` objects, to calling `cor_cophenetic` on the dendrograms, or phylos. Is there a correct way here?

Next, I try to do a randomization test on the labels of `clusts1`.

```
per <- sample(length(clusts1$labels))
clusts1$labels <- clusts1$labels[per]
```

While the cophenetic on the dendros vary on the randomizations (I get a distribution). The direct cophenetic on the `hclusts` stays fixed (0.689649) - and does not change. Why is it?

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember when using cophenetic correlation is that the (cophenetic) distance matrix of the two trees MUST be ordered in the same way so to make the check comparable. So rotating the trees or changing their data type structure should not make a difference on the value. What you are reporting is a potential bug. But I can't reproduce it. Here is an example that gives the proper results:

```
library(dendextend)
dend15 <- c(1:5) %>% dist %>% hclust(method = "average") %>% as.dendrogram %>% set("labels", as.character(labels(.)))
dend51 <- dend15 %>% set("labels", as.character(5:1)) %>% match_order_by_labels(dend15)
dend15_r <- rev(dend15)
tanglegram(dend15 ,dend15_r )
tanglegram(dend15 ,dend51 )

cor_cophenetic(dend15 ,dend15_r )
cor_cophenetic(dend15 ,dend51 )

cor_cophenetic(as.hclust(dend15),as.hclust(dend15_r) )
cor_cophenetic(as.hclust(dend15) ,as.hclust(dend51) )
```

output:

```
> 
> cor_cophenetic(dend15 ,dend15_r )
[1] 1
> cor_cophenetic(dend15 ,dend51 )
[1] 0.3125
> 
> cor_cophenetic(as.hclust(dend15),as.hclust(dend15_r) )
[1] 1
> cor_cophenetic(as.hclust(dend15) ,as.hclust(dend51) )
[1] 0.3125
>
```

First two trees (no topological difference - cor of 1)
[image]

Second comparison of two trees (with a topological difference - cor of 0.31)
[image]

Please create a small self contained example to reproduce this issue, and post it here: https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend/issues

Comment: Hi Tal, thanks for the answer! I looked into it and it seems that when you use cor_cophenetic on objects of type phylo or dendro you don't have to take of the order, while when you pass objects of type hclust you have to pay more attention to the order of the labels.